# Mocap crashing in game mode

Tags: game-engine, motion-capture

I'm controlling a character using a Kinect plus Ni-mate's plugin.  It works fine in Blender Render, but in Blender Game mode it crashes as soon as I hit P.

I need to run in game mode because I want to have interactions between my character and other objects.

I hope someone can help me solve this...

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with using elements created in Blender Cycles which can't be rendered in BGE.